# Error when creating container with golang docker engine

Tags: sockets, go, docker

I am creating a project in Go and I am using both "github.com/docker/docker/client" and "github.com/docker/docker/api/types", but when I try and create a container I get the following error:

> ERROR: 2016/10/03 22:39:26 containers.go:84: error during connect: Post https://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.23/containers/create: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

I can't understand why this is happening and it only happened after using the new golang docker engine(the old "github.com/docker/engine-api" is now deprecated).

The code isn't anything complicated, so I wonder if I am missing something:

```
    resp, err := cli.Pcli.ContainerCreate(context.Background(), initConfig(), nil, nil, "")
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
```

And the initConfig that is called does the following:

```
func initConfig() (config *container.Config) {
    mount := map[string]struct{}{"/root/host": {}}
    return &container.Config{Image: "leadis_image", Volumes: mount, Cmd: strslice.StrSlice{"/root/server.py"}, AttachStdout: true}}
```

Also here is my dockerfile

> FROM        debian
>
> MAINTAINER  Leadis Journey
>
> LABEL   Description="This docker image is used to compile and execute user's program."
>
> LABEL   Version="0.1"
>
> VOLUME  /root/host/
>
> RUN     apt-get update && yes | apt-get upgrade
>
> RUN     yes | apt-get install gcc g++ python3 make
>
> COPY    container.py /root/server.py

**EDIT**

Just tried to test it with a simpler program

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "io/ioutil"
        "github.com/docker/docker/client"
        "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
        "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
        "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/strslice"
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
)


func initConfig() (config *container.Config) {
        mount := map[string]struct{}{"/root/host": {}}
        return &container.Config{Image: "leadis_image", Volumes: mount, Cmd: strslice.StrSlice{"/root/server.py"}, AttachStdout: true}
}

func main() {
        client, _ := client.NewEnvClient()


        cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        ctx, err := os.Open(cwd+"/Dockerfile.tar.gz")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }
        build, err := client.ImageBuild(context.Background(), ctx, types.ImageBuildOptions{Tags: []string{"leadis_image"}, Context: ctx, SuppressOutput: false})
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(build.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(b))
        _, err = client.ContainerCreate(context.Background(), initConfig(), nil, nil, "")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
}
```

Same dockerfile, but I still get the same error:

> error during connect: Post
>   https://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.23/containers/create: http:
>   server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Comment: Looks like your project is enabled https, but your local docker daemon still in plain http. Maybe this doc helps https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Comment: What are the command line options you pass to your docker instance? (`ps -ef | grep docker` What's in your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`? Do you get a standard response to a `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.23/containers/json?all=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
client.NewEnvClient()
```

Last time I tried, this API expects environment variables like `DOCKER_HOST` in a different syntax from than the normal docker client.

From the [client.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/client/client.go#L84):

```
// NewEnvClient initializes a new API client based on environment variables.
// Use DOCKER_HOST to set the url to the docker server.
// Use DOCKER_API_VERSION to set the version of the API to reach, leave empty for latest.
// Use DOCKER_CERT_PATH to load the TLS certificates from.
// Use DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY to enable or disable TLS verification, off by default.
```

To use this, you need DOCKER_HOST to be set/exported in one of these formats:

1. unix:///var/run/docker.sock
2. http://localhost:2375
3. https://localhost:2376